# Better way to indicate “a large amount of ”

Tags: phrase-requests

A [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) tells us that:

> A problem is regarded as inherently difficult if solving the problem requires **a large amount of** resources, whatever the algorithm used for solving it.

What is a more elegant, and perhaps more correct, way of expressing the notion “a large amount of ” in a context like this?

**EDIT** after comments: Maybe what bothers me is the the *large amount* followed by plural *resources*. I like a large amount of butter on my morning toast; and I like having a lot of books around; but I’m not so sure I’d say I like having *a large amount* of books here.

**FINALLY** I changed the sentence to read

> A problem is regarded as inherently
>   difficult if **its solution**
>   requires **significant resources**,
>   whatever the algorithm used.

Comment: Doesn't "a large amount of" sound better than things like "crapload"?

Comment: @Cyclone -- I gotta' give you that one. But, you know, "shitload" is *exactly* the right word. Thanks, pal :-)

Comment: I think "crapload" ought to be a standardized unit of measurement, e.g. "That truck can hold six craploads of concrete bricks!" (Brings a whole new meaning to shit bricks, no?)

Comment: @Cyclone -- LOL! Although the notion "crapload" is infinitely expandable and might not admit of standardization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for a one-word synonym, you could try **significant resources**.

If you want to express that the amount is larger than necessary, or onerously large, you could try **excessive resources**.

Comment: “significant” doesn't imply that the *amount* is significant, though; only that there is some important significance of the resource. “Time is a significant resource” does not imply a large amount of time.

Comment: Sure, if the word is singular as you use it. But when *resources* is plural, *significant* as a modifier usually refers to quantity.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really see anything 'inelegant' about *a large amount of*, but if you just want something shorter, *substantial* or *considerable* would fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the theory in question is concerned about the proportion of available computational resources available to devote to any one problem. In this context, **disproportionate resources** would work well. Since *disproportionate* could also mean *too few*, you may need to qualify it as *a disproportionately large amount of resources*, but I think the simpler phrase remains clear from the context.

Comment: I think OP is concerned with 'difficult' problems as (loosely) defined from the mathematical point of view, whereas *disproportionate* sounds more appropriate in a commercial software context. Pure mathematicians don't really care if their computing demands are *disproportionate*, so long as they can get access to sufficient processing power for whatever they're investigating.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The OP link puts the quote in the context of a definition of computational complexity theory and an explanation of how it differs from analysis of algorithms and computability theory. My suggestion was in response to phrases I read there like _quantifying the amount of resources_, _determine the practical limits_, and _appropriately restricted resources_.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right phrase here is a large number of resources. Amount should be used with a collective noun, such as a large amount of lumber. Number is used with a plural noun, such as a large number of boards.

Comment: No, *number* should only be used with countable nouns. *Resources* in this sense isn't countable (it required seven resources???), so *number* is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I too dislike the phrase "a large amount of," whether followed by a singular or a plural noun. It's simply too wordy. I'd prefer "many" or "lots of" in most contexts, with "substantial" as an alternative in formal writing. One sturdy, straightforward source for this kind of phrase replacement is *The Appropriate Word,* by J.N. Hook (Addison-Wesley, 1990). http://books.google.com/books?id=JqFiAAAAMAAJ

Comment: If you think *that's* too wordy, get a large amount of this, from the blurb of the book (which I like; thanks for that and +1 to you): **"A guide to proper usage for standard written, as well as conversational, English"**  How d'ya like *them* apples, bub? :-)

Answer (score 1):

"A prohibitive amount of resources" would work well here, I think.

Answer (score 1):

How might '**an abundance of**' suit your needs?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abundance

Comment: Yes, even an *overabundance* in this context, where running processes and threads have to compete for the scarce resources the guy is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

"A great deal of [effort]" might be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The standard modifier for this situation is "extensive." Sure, "significant" works, but extensive is better because it's the idiom.

Answer (score 0):

The context of the sentence is in computer science.

The phrase **large amounts of** can be substituted by substantial -

> A problem is regarded as inherently difficult if its solution requires substantial resources, whatever the algorithm used.

The phrase **large amounts of resources** can be substituted by what resources is being consumed.

Lots of money is being consumed:

> A problem is regarded as inherently difficult if its solution is costs-prohibitive.

Lots of time is being taken:

> A problem is regarded as inherently difficult if its solution is time-consuming.

Lots of resources is being consumed:

> The forest fire was very difficult to put out as it required many fire fighters and huge amount of water to extinguish.